# @mixin Invalid CSS after "@mixin

Tags: sass, stylesheet, node-sass

What's wrong with this sass mixin?

```
@mixin tablet {
  @media (min-width: #{$tablet}) and (max-width: #{desktop - 1px})
    {
      @content;
    }
}
```

`node-sass` tells me this error:

```
@mixin tablet {
              ^
      Invalid CSS after "@mixin tablet {": expected "}", was "{"
      in /home/alexzeitler/src/my-prj/mobile-mockups/src/styles/responsive-mixins.sass (line 4, column 16)
```

But [every](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-sass-mixins) [sample](https://marksheet.io/sass-mixins.html) I [look](https://davidwalsh.name/write-media-queries-sass) at, uses my syntax shown above.

Update: 
`./node_modules/.bin/node-sass --version` returns

```
node-sass   4.9.3   (Wrapper)   [JavaScript]
libsass     3.5.4   (Sass Compiler) [C/C++]
```

Comment: In your media queries, you can replace first `max-width: #{desktop - 1px}` by `max-width: #{$desktop - 1px}`

Answer (score 2):

Solution: I messed up file extensions. Using `.scss` instead of `.sass` fixed it.

Also using this SASS syntax will fix it if you want to stick with `.sass` extension:

```
=tablet
  @media (min-width: #{$tablet}) and (max-width: #{desktop - 1px})
      @content

=desktop
  @media (min-width: #{$desktop-width})
  @content
```

Comment: Use `(max-width: #{$desktop - 1px})` may be ?